# Is E4X specification wrong?

Tags: javascript, xml, specifications, e4x

Does anybody know about ECMAScript for XML (E4X; ECMA-357 2º edition) and read its specification? Deprecated, I know. To start my question, please let me point somethings first:

E4X allows expressions like `<x/>`, thus extending *`PrimaryExpression`* with a *`XMLInitialiser | XMLListInitialiser`* production.

However, they say:

> The syntactic grammar for XML initialisers processes input elements produced by the lexical grammar goal symbols InputElementXMLTag and InputElementXMLContent. These input elements are described in section 8.3.

(and same for XML list.)

So, isn't *`XMLInitialiser`* supposed to also process *`InputElementRegExp`*? The specification tries to reject that. Please check these definitions:

*`XMLInitialiser`* :

- *`XMLMarkup`*
- *`XMLElement`*

*`XMLElement`* :

- **<** *`XMLTagContent`* *`XMLWhitespace`*<sup>opt</sup> **/>**

and also,

*`InputElementXMLContent`* ::

- **<**
- and more...

They all make **<** available, but then how would one parse other expressions that need *`InputElementRegExp`*?

Comment: Why would anyone want to do a deep dive into ECMAScript for XML (E4X) in late 2017 given that it's been [**obsolete and deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X) since 2014?

Comment: @kjhughes Because anyone that wants to implement a ActionScript 3 compiler needs to implement ECMAScript for XML, right? Because ActionScript 3.0 extends ECMA-262 (3º edition; ECMAScript 3.0) and ECMA-357 (2º edition).

Comment: I'll refrain from asking why anyone would want to implement an ActionScript 3 compiler in 2017.

Comment: IIRC, At the time that Mozilla was experimenting with E4X, they were also trying to rework the JavaScript grammar so that the decision about `/` starting a division operator or regular expression was done based on the last token.  See [Wayback machine archive of JS2.0 syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20070504025550/http://www.mozilla.org/js/language/js20/rationale/syntax.html), especially the part on "Syntactic Resynchronization."

Answer (score 1):

> So, isn't XMLInitialiser supposed to also process InputElementRegExp?

Yes, `XMLInitialiser` (or `XMLListInitialiser`) would consume `XMLMarkup` elements matched by `InputElementRegExp`.

> The specification tries to reject that.

How so?

> They all make < available, but then how would one parse other expressions that need InputElementRegExp?
>   [In comment:] ... it'd cause a conflict for scanning an `InputElementRegExp` as well as an `InputElementXMLContent`, this is because the `<` symbol comes first in `XMLInitialiser` or `XMLListInitialiser`.

If you're saying that there's a conflict between `InputElementRegExp` and `InputElementXMLContent` because they both derive '<': No, that's not a conflict, because those two symbols are never used at the same point in the input. See the third paragraph in section 8:

"The `InputElementXMLContent` is used in those syntactic contexts where the literal contents of an XML element are permitted. The `InputElementRegExp` symbol is used in all other syntactic grammar contexts."

That is, in any given syntactic context, there should be exactly one lexical goal symbol (`InputElementSomething`) to use.

On the other hand, if you're saying that there's a conflict between `XMLInitiliser` and `XMLListInitialiser` because they both derive sentences beginning with `<`: Well, yes, that would be a problem for an LL(1) parser, but an LL(2) or LR(1) parser could handle it, I believe.

> I believe the < production in the InputElementXMLContent was a mistake.

I don't think so. Consider the example `<A><B/></A>`. After `<A>`, the syntactic parser is expecting `XMLElementContent` or `</`, which means that the lexical parser must use `InputElementXMLContent` as the goal symbol. So the latter must be able to match `<` in order for this parse to succeed.

> [from comment:] `XMLElement` starts with a `<` terminal and may nest other elements, thus, it should be `InputElementRegExp` IMO.

Again, see section 8. The two sentences I quoted above indicate that, after seeing `<A>`, you must use `InputElementXMLContent` to get the next input element.

Comment: 1) Not sure what you're trying to mean. `XMLMarkup` only includes **CDATA**, _comment_ and _PI_. I already implemented those in my deleted scanner, much like chunks. I know  `InputElementRegExp` as well as `
InputElementXMLContent` include the `XMLMarkup` production symbol. 3) My terminology wasn't easy. I was trying to mean that it'd cause a conflict for scanning an `InputElementRegExp` as well as an `InputElementXMLContent`, this is because the **<** symbol comes first in `XMLInitialiser` or `XMLListInitialiser`.

Comment: 4) No such example. Assuming this conclusion is wrong, `XMLElement` starts with a **<** terminal and may nest other elements, thus, it should be `InputElementRegExp` IMO.

Comment: 1) "`XMLMarkup` only includes CDATA, comment and PI. ... I know `InputElementRegExp` as well as `InputElementXMLContent` include the `XMLMarkup` production symbol." Agreed, but I'm no closer to understanding your question/difficulty.

Comment: 4) "No such example." I suppose you mean that that code example doesn't appear in the spec, but I just meant it was an example of a valid sentence in the language. The spec certainly has examples of nested elements, but they're not as simple. See 10.1.1, 11.1.2, 11.1.4, 11.2.1, ...

Comment: 4) "it should be InputElementRegExp IMO": Edited my response to address that.

Answer (score 0):

This just gave me an headache. But, re-looking up the section 8, there's an example where,

```
order = <{x}>{item}</{x}>;
```

is equivalent to

(specification bitmap)

[image: table]

I believe the **<** production in the *`InputElementXMLContent`* was a mistake.